# How can I pass the antrun plugin a new environment variable?

Tags: maven, install4j, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using the maven-antrun-plugin with install4j to build installers for my application.  It doesn't work if java is not on the (system) path.  Since it's forking a new java process to run the task, there must be a way I can pass it environment variables, but I can't figure it out.

Install4J will use `EXE4J_JAVA_HOME` to select a java installation.  I want to pass that to ant via the antrun-plugin.  I can think of a few hackish ways of doing it, but there's got to be something simple I'm overlooking.  For reference, here is my antrun config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>

            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                    <taskdef name="install4j" classname="com.install4j.Install4JTask"
                        classpath="${install4j.ant.path}"/>

                    <install4j projectfile="itma-assembly-client-swing.install4j" buildids="62">
                        <variable name="verbose.version.number" value="${verbose-version-number}"/>
                        <variable name="media.file.prefix" value="${media-file-prefix}"/>
                        <variable name="main.class" value="${itma-client-swing-bootstrap-main-class}"/>
                    </install4j>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question ... I did some research on it and found the *property*-Task for Ant which did sound promising first but it allows only read-access on environment variables. These sources on [jguru](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1154289) and [coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/109081/tools/set-environmental-variables-ANT) claim that an  is the only way to pass environment variables from inside Ant.
It's not the nicest way but perhaps you can exec the com.install4j.Install4JTask from the command-line aka via exec - perhaps that's one of your hackish ways ... :-)

Comment: The suggestion of using exec is the best I've ever been able to come up with for this, so I've accepted this answer.  Even with Gradle the only way I was able to make this work was to ignore the provided ant tasks and exec the commands directly.  Also, `EXE4J_JAVA_HOME` and `INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE` only seem to work on linux with earlier versions of Install4j (4.2.8), at least for me.